# An alternative to using negative margin?

Tags: html, css, margin

I am using negative margin's to place my image on the background however when i zoom to much it shifts and distorts the image to a great deal. On zooming the box on the right goes towards the top because of the negative margin.

Please find below the code i am using:-

```
  <div class="platform-row" style="float: right; margin-right: 145px; padding: 2px;">
            <span><a href="download/index.html">
                <img src="assets/Box.png" border="0" /></a></span><br>
            <div class="platform-row-box">
                SOME TEXT GOES HERE...................
            </div>

            <a href="download/index.html">
                <div class="getmxit">Get ABC Now</div>
            </a>
            <div style="background: black; margin-top: 3px; width: 181px; opacity: .8; padding: 2px">

                <span><a class="platform-icon apple" href="download/ios/index.html"></a></span>
                <span><a class="platform-icon android" href="download/android/index.html"></a></span>

            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .platform-row {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    margin-top: -530px;
    margin-left: 700px;
}

    .platform-row .platform-row-box {
        color: white;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 181px;
        opacity: .8;
        margin-top: -170px;
        position: fixed;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .platform-row {
        padding-right: 55%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .platform-row {
        margin-top: 40px;
        padding-right: 35%;
    }
}

.platform-icon {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    /**background-image: url("platform_icons-14a66f5cbf10a328f7b38e6070c26e62.png");**/
    background-image: url("Home_Get.png");
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2 / 1), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    .platform-icon {
        background-image: url("platform_icons%402x-dfed2cc115fa8b344e08c9072408095a.png");
        background-size: 454px 88px;
        -webkit-background-size: 454px 88px;
    }
}
```

[image]

EDIT:

**This is what happens when i zoom in too much because of the negative margin.**

[image]

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Can you make a jsfiddle where you only show the code needed to reproduce the problem, please? Many times, while doing a jsfiddle for a question I am able to solve the problem myself

Comment: As mentioned a jsfiddle would help alot. Also why are you using the inline styling along with the CSS?

Comment: What browser have you witnessed this on and what window size were you using?  A fiddle would be useful with links to your images in particular.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disclaimer: This answer is based on what I think you're asking.  For a more specific solution to your problem, please be more specific with regard to what you're trying to achieve.

It looks like you're using negative margins and padding to compensate for the fact that your image is relatively positioned (by default).  To avoid breaking your layout you can achieve the same thing with one of two approaches:

Method 1 (not ideal): Move your background image outside of its current container and into the broader document context.  Then position your image absolutely so that it doesn't effect the rest of your layout:

```
HTML
<img class="background" src="somedir/background.png">
<div class="platform-row">....</div>

CSS
.background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;  /* defining the top/left/bottom/right declarations are important! */
    left: 0;
    /* bottom: 0; apply these two if you want your image to stretch and fill the entire viewport */
       /*right: 0; */
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Method 2 (better): Just apply the background image as a `background` to the body (or preferably a max height/width wrapper).

```
HTML
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="platform-row">....</div>
    <!-- other page content -->
</div> <!-- end of page-wrapper -->



CSS
.page-wrapper {
    background: transparent url('/images/background.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    /* fix the image in place (not supported in older browsers) */
    background-position: fixed;
}
```

Also, instead of using margins to position your `.platform-row-box`, you can simply use the `position: fixed` style (which you've already defined), but you'll need to define the `top/right/bottom/left` values.

```
.platform-row-box {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    right: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Hi i tried out the second method still get the space at the top as seen in the edited question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'zoom in'?

Comment: So if the user views it in the small screen like an ipad or iphone i get the screen that is given above in my edit

Answer (score 13):

For those who are looking for a simple, good alternative to negative margin:

**Bad**, causes document flow confusion:

```
margin-top: -2px;
```

**Good**, Instead:

```
position: relative;
top: -2px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a positive value to opposite side margin along with float(means if you want to move left by -20px, give float right to that div and give positive value for right margin